# Would it make sense to provide a sample for arbitrary code generation?

Tags: handlebars.js

i am new to handlebars. I am seeking for a general way to create code from templates via some kind of input data. I found handlebars quite good for this purpose. But wheras the documentation is centered on server side / browser online templating (html). My runtime would be the shell. I read and tried handlebars-cmd... with limited success. I don't know how to include my own helpers or libraries like handlebars-helpers in handlebars-cmd.

Can anybody help me with an example?

Comment: If you want to share something like that you should instead present it like a question and then answer your own question (as a FAQ) so that people would see what the problem could be and what is the solution. Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted so that people will know that you don't need a better answer.

Comment: i will edit the question and add an answer to it. Thx for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to write a sample.

I hope this small piece of code can help others to run and test their templates as well as their helpers and partials ... perhaps it is worth to include this in a example directory or the documentation...

i would like to share my first rough sample that runs in node.js 
just with

```
npm i handlebars
npm i handlebars-helpers
npm i minimist

node hbrscmd.js --in some.json --template template.hbs --out myresult.txt
```

content of hbrscmd.js:

```
    var hbs = require('handlebars');
    var helpers = require('handlebars-helpers')({
        handlebars: hbs
    });

    var fs = require('fs');
    var args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
    if (args.hasOwnProperty("v")) {
        console.log(args);
    }

    var datastring = fs.readFileSync(args.in, 'utf8');
    var data = JSON.parse(datastring);
    if (args.hasOwnProperty("v")) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    var templatefile = fs.readFileSync(args.template, 'utf8');
    //console.log(templatefile);
    var template = hbs.compile(templatefile);
    var output = template(data);

    fs.writeFileSync(args.out, output);
```

this works as i like.
No checking is made.